# refreshing cahche assignment thread safety

Tags: java, thread-safety

```
public class Test {

    Set<Integer> cache = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();

    // multiple threads call this
    public boolean contain(int num) {
        return cache.contains(num);
    }

    // background thread periodically calls this
    private void refresh() {
        Set<Integer> newSet = getNums();
        cache = newSet; // is this assignment thread safe?
    }

    private Set<Integer> getNums() {
         Set<Integer> newSet = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();
         // read numbers from file and add them to newSet
         return newSet;
    }
}
```

I have a cache refresh logic as shown above and like to make sure that it's thread safe and right way to do it.

I have a background thread periodically calls `refresh`. `contain` is called by multiple threads.

In `refresh`, I have `cache = newSet`. Is this thread-safe? What will happen if `cache.contains` and `cache = newSet` executed at the exactly same time? It's possible that one thread is calling `contains` while the background thread is running `refresh`.

Also, since `contain` only call `cache.contains` function, do I need `newConcurrentHashSet`?

Answer (score 1):

> In refresh, I have cache = newSet. Is this thread-safe?

It is not 100% thread safe as cache is not marked with `volatile` keyword. In this case even if the assignment is an atomic operation in the JVM, when one thread access the `cache.contains` and another thread does the assignment (refresh), the change may not be immediately visible to both threads.

Since `volatile` keyword guarantees visibility of shared state among multiple threads whenever there is a change.

> Also, since contain only call cache.contains function, do I need
>   newConcurrentHashSet?

If there is no modification to `cache` by any threads but only reading it should could use a non concurrent set also. But in that case you need to make `cache` variable `private`.

```
    public class Test {

        private volatile Set<Integer> cache = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();

        // multiple threads call this
        public boolean contain(int num) {
            return cache.contains(num);
        }

        // background thread periodically calls this
        private void refresh() {
            Set<Integer> newSet = getNums();
            cache = newSet; // is this assignment thread safe?
        }

        private Set<Integer> getNums() {
             Set<Integer> newSet = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();
             // read numbers from file and add them to newSet
             return newSet;
        }
    }
```

Comment: with making cache volatile, is `cache = newSet` thread-safe? `cache.contains(num)` and `cache = newSet` can be called at the same time, is it still okay?

Comment: @codereviewanskquestions A shared mutable state needs to be synchronized access only if more than 1 thread access it and at least 1 thread modifies it. In this case there is no modification by any thread after assignment. Only reassigning of an entirely new collection. no modification to the existing collection.